# Highest CPU utilisation process in linux

Tags: linux, ps

I want find highest cpu utilisation process.I am using

```
ps -aux|awk -F " " '{print $2" ,"$3}'|sort -r | head -5
```

Please help me if this is right or wrong command.I am getting 'Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.7/FAQ'

Comment: Add your shell as a tag; that's more important than the 'unix' tag.

Comment: I am working on Linux .

Comment: ps  doesn't take - in front of aux. That's how you get the warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps aux --sort %cpu | tail -n 1
user    5627  7.6 16.0 1928396 1331680 ?     Sl   Mar12 120:58 /opt/firefox/firefox
```

-n 1  gives the highest, adjust number to give highest x processes. Tail because default (+) for --sort is lowest to highest.

To get just the top cpu itself though that's not particularly useful:

```
ps aux --sort %cpu | tail -n 1 |awk '{print $3}'
7.6
```

To get it with the headers use highest to lowest (-) sort:

```
ps aux --sort -%cpu | head -n 2
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
user    5627  7.6 16.0 1928396 1331680 ?     Sl   Mar12 120:58 /opt/firefox/firefox
```